# Created Custom Site Column - Not appearing in some connected Hub Site Collections - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-column

Custom Columns available on one Team Site – but not the other two Team sites - all are connected to the Hub Site. All the Team sites are OOTB and new.

Any help is appreciated.

Kind Regards

David

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you use the **content type syndication hub sites**, not the newly announced SharePoint hub sites.

Reference: [Publish a content type from a content publishing hub.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/publish-a-content-type-from-a-content-publishing-hub-58081155-118d-4e7a-9cc5-d43b5dbb7d02)

--

The published content types technically but not necessarily get updated every time the **content type subscriber timer job** runs. The job runs every hour, but it can take up to 4 hours for the update to take effect.

Since we have no control for the timer jobs in SharePoint Online, I would suggest you wait a little longer for the result.

A few things you can check for basic troubleshooting:

1. Go to the other two Team sites and check if the content type is listed under **Subscribed Content Type** via `Site settings > Content type publishing`.
2. If not, go back to Content Type Hub Site and check for potential **Content type publishing error log**.
3. **Republish** the content type.
4. Select **Refresh all published content types on next update** and then click **OK**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply.

The steps I have taken given your info.

1. Hub (Hubsite) - enabled site collection feature - Enabled Content Type Syndication Hub
2. Selected Site content types (Web Design Galleries)
3. Selected Site Page content type (I'm trying to add custom columns to news pages)
4. Selected Manage publishing for this content type

I then receive a 403 FORBIDDEN error.

Checked Teams sites and they are (obviously) not subscribed to a content type.

What am I doing wrong?

Any further help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I also get a 403 error when trying to access Content type publishing error log.

Comment: I also read that the legacy Content Hub, is a bit outdated and has limitations. Scratching my head here. lol

Comment: I came across this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/inheritance-of-a-content-type-from-a-sharepoint/e051cab3-afbb-4dc4-aa9c-fe1a7ea42f79  - it looks like it is not possible?

Comment: @Fitz The post you read is talking about SharePoint Hub Site (not Content Type Hub). Also I’ve tested and confirmed that this feature is still working at present. I’ve noticed something strange though. The published content type is not listed under the Content Type Hub but is available in all other team sites.

Comment: @Fitz Troubleshooting suggestions: 1. Make sure you use a global admin/SharePoint admin account. 2. Make sure you published the content type using the site “https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/contentTypeHub”. 3. Add your account to the Site collection administrators list in this site. 4. Republish the content type.